# Как получить только цифры из массива?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Суть такая, я вытаскиваю из базы данных SQlite3 номера id которые добавляются мне в массив, а мне нужны отдельные числа, подскажите пожалуйста как такое можно сделать?
Вот немного кода:

```
searching_object = f"{message.text}"
    cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM ads WHERE feature1 = '%s'" % searching_object)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(result) # Результат: [(3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это список кортежей. Можете просто взять из кортежей первые элементы:

```
result = [(3,), (4,), (5,)]
result = [x[0] for x in result]
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

`SQL` возвращает кортежи потому, что вы же можете сделать `select` не только одного поля, но и нескольких, поэтому возвращается кортеж из значений выбранных полей. Даже если поле только одно, возвращается всё-равно кортеж из одного элемента, как в вашем случае.